# Understanding relational database, including friends and posts for each friend - Parse

Tags: relational-database, parse-platform

*Sorry I had this question in the help section of parse.com, but now they decided to move to stackoverflow for their questions.*

I'm trying to make a facebook-like app in iOS, just to test Parse and see if it will work for a business project. I apologize for this question, but I don't have any knowledge on relational databases.

Here are my classes: User Posts Comments

Inside user, I have a column called "array_friends" which has an array of PFUsers (pointers) that are the friends of my current user. What I'm trying to do is:

1.- query my current user for all of his posts

2.- query my current user for how many comments each of his posts has

3.- query my current user to get his list of friends (which returns an array of PFUser)

4.- query each individual friend (PFUser) for this user's posts as well

5.- query each individual friend for this user's comments count for each of his posts

I can do items 1, 2 and 3 but that's about it, and I think item 3 has issues too. For item 3 (query my own list of friends), I'm doing this:

```
NSArray *allFriendsObjects = [currentUser objectForKey:@"array_friends"];
```

But the issue is that it returns this:

```
"<PFUser:U0ivpIhDvx:(null)> {\n}"
```

So the question is now, how do I efficiently (without doing n number of loops) query for all of the comments of each user that is a friend with my account? I'm basically stuck on items 4 and 5.

Let me know if you need additional information.

Thank you.

**Update**

PFQuery using  Timothy Walters' suggestions:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFUser query];
[query includeKey:@"array_friends"];
[query getObjectInBackgroundWithId:[[PFUser currentUser] objectId]
                             block:^(PFObject *userWithFriends, NSError *error)
 {
     NSArray *allFriendsObjects = userWithFriends[@"array_friends"];
     NSLog(@"allFriendsObjects = %@", allFriendsObjects);

     PFQuery *postsQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Post"];
     [postsQuery whereKey:@"user" containedIn:allFriendsObjects];
     [postsQuery getObjectInBackgroundWithId:[[PFUser currentUser]objectId]
                                       block:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error)
     {
                                           NSLog(@"object = %@", object);
    }];
}];
```

Then the first query returns this (which is good):

```
allFriendsObjects = (
"<PFUser:U0ivpIhDvx:(null)> {\n    email = \"demo@demo.com\";\n    \"name_first\" = Demo;\n    \"name_last\" = Tester;\n    \"profile_picture\" = \"<PFFile: 0x9b6cb90>\";\n    username = \"demo@demo.com\";\n}",
"<PFUser:HjZJpWkejl:(null)> {\n    email = \"tester@test.com\";\n    \"name_first\" = test;\n    \"name_last\" = test;\n    username = \"tester@test.com\";\n}"
```

)

But then the second query (postsQuery) returns this:

```
Error: no results matched the query (Code: 101, Version: 1.2.19)
object = (null)
```

Here's how my classes look like in Parse:
User class
[image]

Posts class
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In regards to comment counts, you should use Cloud Code to keep a number updated, there's a sample in the documentation for Posts saving the count of Comments:

https://parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide#functions-aftersave

You could extend this to also increment a `commentCount` on the `User` too. Then you just read a number property on the User/Post to know how many comments there are without having to do massive queries.

In regards to number 3, just do a query on the User class and call `includeKey:` to get all friends back in the one query:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFUser query];
[query includeKey:@"array_friends"];
[query getObjectInBackgroundWithId:[[PFUser currentUser] objectId]
                             block:^(PFObject *userWithFriends, NSError *error) {
    NSArray *allFriendsObjects = userWithFriends[@"array_friends"];
    // do something with results...
}];
```

In regards to number 4, use your saved friends array:

```
PFQuery *postsQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Post"];
[postsQuery whereKey:@"author" containedIn:allFriendsObjects];
[postsQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *posts, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Posts: %@", posts);
}];
```

This will get back all posts for all friends (there's a limit of 1000 max records per query, 100 is the default limit)... you could split them by author client-side if you need to or show them in a combined list.

I would suggest something like sorting by `createdAt` descending, paging 20 or so records at a time.

Comment: The idea of the commentCount is definitely good so thank you for that.

I can already do #3 though. What I'm truly struggling with is #4: query each individual friend (PFUser) for this user's posts as well

Comment: @TooManyEduardos added sample for #4 too. Also note that with my #3 solution you get full `PFUser` objects for each friend, not just pointers that you'll need to call `fetch` on, as a result of `includeKey:`.

Comment: Tim I updated my question with the code you suggested and it's reponse. Basically the first query works but the second one doesn't.
Any idea on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @TooManyEduardos Your update is incorrectly filtering posts by using `getObjectInBackgroundWithId:block:`, trying to find a `Post` with an objectId of the current user. Use `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:` instead.

Comment: I did that, but it didn't return anything now from the array.
This is my new query, inside the main query:
         PFQuery *postsQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Posts"];
         [postsQuery whereKey:@"user" containedIn:allFriendsObjects];
         [postsQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error)
         {
             NSLog(@"objects = %@", objects);
         }];

This query returns objects = (
)
Any idea?

Comment: It seems like this is working now. I remade the data set in Parse and I'm now getting objects back from the second query.
I'm still looking at what the problem was (to not do it again), but since this is somewhat working now I've marked this as the correct answer.

Thank you very much!

Comment: One issue I would be careful with is naming. It is better to use singular names for classes, not plural, e.g. "Comment" and "Post" instead of "Comments" and "Posts", in keeping with how Parse names things. That'll help avoid confusion later.

Comment: Oh cool, thanks. For now this is just a test project to see if I can do with Parse what I want to do.